# Diamond inheritance and pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

Imagine a standard diamond inheritance. Class A defines pure virtual function fx, class B defines implementation for fx, classes C and D do nothing with fx. When trying to call fx on instance of class D you'll get 'ambiguous function call' error although there is only one implementation of fx. This can be solved by B and C inheriting from A in virtual manner. Is it a *correct* solution for the problem? How exactly does virtual inheritance handle merging of virtual function tables?

A--->B--->D

\--->C------^

Answer (score 19):

... Note, Herb Sutter wrote 3 excellent articles about multiple inheritance [(1) here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/037.htm), [(2) here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/038.htm) and [(3) here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/039.htm) . He wrote a whole other bunch of useful articles in guru-of-the-week [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/). Highly recommended ...

First, i'm not sure that i get your hierarchy right. I take it it is like this:

```
struct A {
    virtual void F() = 0;
};

struct B : A { void F() { } };
struct C : A { };
struct D : B, C { };
```

Well, D is abstract, because there are two `A` subobjects in an object of type D: One that is made concrete by `B` through the lattice of B, and one that is still abstract in the lattice going through `C`. I take it you have a pointer to `D` and try to call `F`. Yes, an ambiguity arises, because the compiler finds two functions `F` in two separate lattices:

```
D -> B::F
D -> C -> A::F
```

Looking like this:

```
    F()   F()
     A     A
     |     |
 F() B     C
      \   /
        D
```

You can fix that situation formally by deriving from A virtually:

```
struct B : virtual A { void F() { } };
struct C : virtual A { };
struct D : B, C { };
```

You then have this situation, called diamond inheritance:

```
       F()  
        A
      /   \
 F() B     C
      \   /
        D
```

And doing the lookup, it finds that there is `B::F` overriding `A::F`. Although `A::F` can still be reached through `D::C::A`, that is not an ambiguity anymore, because `A` was inherited virtual.

Whether this is the correct solution in your particular problem - that's of course not certain. There are most often better ways than deriving virtual from a class. To your question about merging of virtual function tables - that's completely depending on the implementation. `GCC`, as far as i know, will keep a pointer to the one A instance in the virtual table of `D`, if we derive virtual.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've asked about. If the functionality is compiler-implementation-dependent it's no way to go.

Comment: the behavior is the same for every compiler - it's the way compilers achieve it that is different. You can trust compilers that they behave like each other, as long as you don't depend on a particular layout of the object (like, the sizeof value) that would depend on an implementation.

Comment: Ok, let me ask more precisely: If there's diamond virtual inheritance and there is a function defined in both A and B, but not in C, can I access the function via D? And which one would that be, the one defined in A or the one from B? Is the behaviour consistent for all compilers?

Comment: B is called, because it overrides the function F in A. as long as there is no function F in C (which would introduce an ambiguity then - there is no unique final overrider for A::F), you are fine calling it on a D object and the one in B is called, for all conforming compilers of course.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a *correct* solution for the problem?

"Diamond" inheritance is problematic, and the *correct* explanation of the solution takes a bit of explaining. I recommend you read the following chapters of Meyers' *Effective C++*:

- Item 26, *Guard against potential ambiguity*
- Item 43, *Use multiple inheritance judiciously*.