# Multiple inheritance and pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

The following code:

```
struct interface_base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct interface : public interface_base
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct implementation_base : public interface_base
{
    void foo();
};

struct implementation : public implementation_base, public interface
{   
    void bar();
};

int main()
{
    implementation x;
}
```

fails to compile with the following errors:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:23:20: error: cannot declare variable 'x' to be of abstract type 'implementation'
test.cpp:16:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'implementation':
test.cpp:3:18: note:    virtual void interface_base::foo()
```

I have played around with it and figured out that making the 'interface -> interface_base' and 'implementation_base -> interface_base' inheritances virtual, fixes the problem, but I don't understand why. Can someone please explain what is going on?

p.s. I omitted the virtual destructors on purpose to make the code shorter. Please don't tell me to put them in, I already know :)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457609/diamond-inheritance-and-pure-virtual-functions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have *two* `interface_base` base classes in your inheritance tree. This means you must provide *two* implementations of `foo()`. And calling either of them will be really awkward, requiring multiple casts to disambiguate. This usually is not what you want.

To resolve this, use virtual inheritance:

```
struct interface_base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct interface : virtual public interface_base
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct implementation_base : virtual public interface_base
{
    void foo();
};

struct implementation : public implementation_base, virtual public interface
{   
    void bar();
};

int main()
{
    implementation x;
}
```

With virtual inheritance, only one instance of the base class in question is created in the inheritance heirarchy for all virtual mentions. Thus, there's only one `foo()`, which can be satisfied by `implementation_base::foo()`.

For more information, [see this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457609/diamond-inheritance-and-pure-virtual-functions) - the answers provide some nice diagrams to make this all more clear.

Comment: Is there a way for me to say "use the implementation from `implementation_base`" for both implementations of `foo()`, without using virtual inheritance?

Comment: @HighCommander4, you could derive interface from `implementation_base` or vice versa, thus eliminating the diamond and creating a linear inheritance tree. Other than that, no, but if you want to hide it, you could make `interface_base` and `interface` empty wrappers that virtually derive from the _real_ interface class.

Answer (score 13):

The **usual C++ idiom** is:

- **public virtual** inheritance for **interface** classes
- **private non-virtual** inheritance for **implementation** classes

In this case we would have:

```
struct interface_base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct interface : virtual public interface_base
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct implementation_base : virtual public interface_base
{
    void foo();
};

struct implementation : private implementation_base,
                        virtual public interface
{   
    void bar();
};
```

In `implementation`, the unique `interface_base` virtual base is :

- publicly inherited via `interface`: `implementation` --public--> `interface` --public--> `interface_base`
- privately inherited via `implementation_base`: `implementation` --private--> `implementation_base` --public--> `interface_base`

When client code does one of these derived to base conversions:

- derived to base pointer conversions,
- reference binding of base type with an initializer of static type derived,
- access to inherited base class members via a lvalue of derived static type,

what matters is only that there is a least *one* accessible inheritance path from the derived class to the given base class subobject; other inaccessible paths are simply ignored. Because inheritance of the base class is only virtual here, there is only one base class subject so these conversions are never ambiguous.

Here, the conversion from `implementation` to  `interface_base`, can always be done by client code via `interface`; the other inaccessible path does not matter at all. **The unique `interface_base` virtual base is publicly inherited from `implementation`.**

In many cases, the implementation classes (`implementation`, `implementation_base`) will be kept hidden from client code: only pointers or references to the interface classes (`interface`, `interface_base`) will be exposed.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "public virtual inheritance for interface classes" is "the (or a) usual C++ idiom". Maybe it should be, but from what I can tell it surely isn't.

Comment: @PaulGroke Hum.. you may be right. Proper idiom? recommended idiom?

Comment: I wrote "maybe it should be", because I'm honestly not sure if it should. I almost never use virtual inheritance (in fact I'm not sure if I *ever* used it in production code). So I don't know the problems it can cause and which of those problems also affect virtual inheritance with pure interface classes (i.e. trivial ctor, trivial dtor, no data).

Comment: I'm also interested in this "public virtual inheritance for interface classes" thing. I didn't hear it anywhere before. Though it sounds applicable in most cases (for interfaces). Can you recall any sources? I cannot google anything suitable.

Comment: @Mikhail Mostly The original books (should I say bibles?) by Stroustrup: TC++PL, D&E (read these decades ago, not quite sure).

Answer (score 2):

For the case of 'solving' the diamond inheritance problem, the solutions offered by bdonlan are valid. Having said that, you can avoid the diamond-problem with design. Why must every instance of a given class be seen as both classes? Are you ever going to pass this same object to a class that says something like:

```
void ConsumeFood(Food *food);
void ConsumeDrink(Drink *drink);

class NutritionalConsumable {
  float calories() = 0;
  float GetNutritionalValue(NUTRITION_ID nutrition) = 0;
};
class Drink : public NutritionalConsumable {
  void Sip() = 0;
};
class Food : public NutritionalConsumable {
  void Chew() = 0;
};
class Icecream : public Drink, virtual public Food {};

void ConsumeNutrition(NutritionalConsumable *consumable) {
  ConsumeFood(dynamic_cast<Food*>(food));
  ConsumeDrink(dynamic_cast<Drink*>(drink));
}

// Or moreso
void ConsumeIcecream(Icecream *icecream) {
  ConsumeDrink(icecream);
  ConsumeFood(icecream);
}
```

Surely it would be better in this case for `Icecream` to just implement `NutritionalConsumable` and provide a `GetAsDrink()` and `GetAsFood()` method that will return a proxy, purely for the sake of appearing as either food or drink. Otherwise that suggests that there is a method or object that accepts a `Food` but somehow wants to later see it as a `Drink`, which can only be achieved with a `dynamic_cast`, and needn't be the case with a more appropriate design.

Comment: Your example is rather different than mine. In my case, `implementation` derives from `interface` because it will be used polymorphically as an `interface*`, and it derives from `implementation_base` to reuse the implementation of the `interface_base` portion of `interface`.

Comment: Ok, so who needs to see it as an `implementation_base`? And who communicates with `interface` but not `interface_base`? What was the thinking behind `implementation_base` inheriting from `interface_base` rather than `interface`? Although my questions are pretty abstract, are you solving a real system design or just the diamond problem?

Comment: No one needs to see it as an `implementation_base`, I could have just derived it from `interface` and duplicated the implementation inside `implementation_base` - but I don't want to duplicate things.

Comment: See [C++ private inheritance](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/private_inheritance.php)

Comment: I'm familiar with private inheritance, but I don't see how it helps me. If I derive `implementation` from `implementation_base` privately, then `foo()` will not be publically accessible to users of `implementation`.

Comment: Perhaps I should have written it as, "See [C++ composition vs private inheritance](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/private_inheritance.php)". The article / tutorial not only discusses where and when to use it, it also quotes a fundamental statement from Scott Meyers, as well as showing you how to make `foo()` publicly available by writing `using interface_base::foo;`.

Comment: "_If I derive implementation from implementation_base privately_" **and** publicly from `interface`