# NDK/JNI - C++ Virtual Inheritance Implementation

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am just getting started with the Android NDK and I'm having some issues understanding how to properly implement inheritance of virtual methods in C++ classes.

I have the following classes:

```cpp
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class IB :
    public virtual IA
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}

class A :
    public IA
{
public:
    void foo();
}

class B :
    public A,
    public IB
{
    void bar();
}
```

And the equivalent Java classes:

```java
public class A extends Pointer
{
    public native void foo();
}

public class B extends A
{
    public native void bar();
}
```

But I get the following compiler errors:

```
note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'B'
virtual void foo() = 0;

error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'B'
return new B();
```

The problem seems to be resolved if I override `foo()` in `B`, i.e.:

```cpp
class B :
    public A,
    public IB
{
    void bar();

    // Overridden from A
    void foo();
}

void B::foo()
{
    A::foo();
}
```

```java
public class B extends A
{
    public native void bar();

    @Override
    public native void foo();
}
```

However I can't understand why this is necessary. If someone could help me understand this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple inheritance and pure virtual functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696473/multiple-inheritance-and-pure-virtual-functions)

Comment: Thanks @Michael, this fixed the issue!